# exclude filter condition in layered navigation

Tags: magento2, filter, catalogsearch

I want to hide products with certain attribute values. If I simply filter the collection in catalog, then faceted data for the filters will not match resulting products.
Igor Minyaylo [said](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/167435/filter-magento-2-product-collection-with-custom-text-like-catalog-search/167451#167451) that recommended extension point is the addFieldToFilter method in fulltext collection. Though, I can't specify the condition type and therefore use the "not in" or rather "not match" filter.
Fulltext search might lose it's speed with such conditions, so I'm curious what's the recommended way to exclude some products.
P.S. I'd like to avoid changing filter type in the layered navigation.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up modifying select with left join after applyFilters method in the CatalogSearch's FilterMapper class.

Comment: could u please guide me how to do that, if possible could u please share the code