# Incorrect product count in layered navigation after overriding list product collection

Tags: magento2, collection, layered-navigation, product-collection

I have customized(override) product list collection `getProductCollection` and filtered collection as required.

```
public function getProductCollection()
    {
        if (isset($this->_productCollections[$this->getCurrentCategory()->getId()])) {
            $collection = $this->_productCollections[$this->getCurrentCategory()->getId()];
        } else {
            $collection = $this->collectionProvider->getCollection($this->getCurrentCategory());
            $this->prepareProductCollection($collection);
            $this->_productCollections[$this->getCurrentCategory()->getId()] = $collection;
        }

        /* custom filter conditions */
        $productUniqueIds = array(10,11,12,13);
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id',array('in' => $productUniqueIds));
        /* custom filter conditions end here */

        return $collection;
    }
```

**Based on above products conditions, My result for listing page will be fine but layered navigation result is not proper, displays wrong filter attributes.**

I am facing an issue in the layered navigation product count after applying filters on product collection. All counts are wrong. What I guess is I need to apply custom filters on layered navigation's collection as well, but I am not able to find it so far.

I have debugged and reached till `_createItem` function in `vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/AbstractFilter.php` file. Product counts are coming from there, but I couldn't find from where exactly product collection gets returned.

Please share your ideas if you have. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is a Magento Bug, You can see here : https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7730

You can take a pull changes from here : https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/10246/files

Apply changes and check your count issue, Hope it might be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look on classs

`Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Search\Plugin\CollectionFilter`

On this plugin class at metod `afterFilter`, Magento add query search by  below code

```
$collection->addSearchFilter($query->getQueryText());
```

This comment this code and see what happen.

Comment: Hello @AmitBera, It looks like collection doesn't filter from this function cause for debug I just added `exit();` on top of function but page still works and nothing changed.

Comment: Not working for Magento 2.4.6

Answer (score 0):

Please try to override getProductCollection() of this class

`/var/www/html/m222/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Layer.php`

Set you custom collection here and then check.

Comment: We have already overide  getProductCollection() function

Comment: @Rakesh Jesadiya You have to override collection of product. Need to try collection of Layer.

Comment: @DharmendraJadav I have overrides Layer.php's getProductCollection but the layernavigation shows wrong data for filter options and wrong toolbar's count I have M2.4.1 and elastic search. Any hint or solution? I even haven't found any blog on it. All links that I have found is not working with M 2.4 version

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya I have overrides Layer.php's getProductCollection but the layernavigation shows wrong data for filter options and wrong toolbar's count I have M2.4.1 and elastic search. Any hint or solution? I even haven't found any blog on it. All links that I have found is not working with M 2.4 version.  I checked your link https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/apply-custom-conditions-for-product-collection-in-magento-2/ but it is not working for M 2.4 as some files are not present in M2.4

Comment: Facing same issue Magento 2.4.6 any solution friends? @RakeshJesadiya