# I am getting incorrect count of products for layered navigation in magento 2.3

Tags: product, magento2.3, collection, layered-navigation, filter

In layered navigation filter i am getting incorrect product count, i can't get the solution for this problem.

Example :

The products under **Shorts** category in **49** but in the filter for me showing as **12**.

[image]

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: try this link --- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/230344/85907

Comment: I can't understand the solution what they give can post here what i need to do please.